# Attempting to run threads concurrently inside while loop in Python 3.11

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, concurrency, python-multithreading

I am trying to get my head around threading in Python 3.11 and I am trying to work out why when I put a `time.sleep(120)` inside `execute_subtasks` that the next thread is not processed and the code appears to run sequentially instead of concurrently.

Do I need to `start` the thread outside of the `for` loop or do I need to move the location of the `join`?

```py
from threading import Thread, Event, active_count, current_thread

threads = list()
while True:
    try:
        # ignore the main thread
        if active_count() > 1:
            for index, thread in enumerate(threads):
                thread.join()

        for message in queue.get_messages(4):
            if active_count() >= config.maxthreads + 1:
                # Thread pool is about to overflow. Skipping.
                continue

            x = threading.Thread(
                target=message.get_task().execute_subtasks,
                daemon=True,
                args=[message.get_context()]
            )
            threads.append(x)
            x.start()
    except Exception:
        # Exception in dispatch loop
```

Comment: Are you sure you're not blocking on the queue?

Comment: @Pingu thanks for the comment. Do you mean not returning more than one `message` at a time? Yes, I checked that and can confirm that I have a list (multiple) of messages to process.

Comment: Is this a BOTO3 queue?

Comment: @Pingu it's an AWS SQS queue and I am sure there are multiple entries to iterate over as I have some logging just about that which shows the number of messages (2 in this instance)

Comment: I think your *for* loop runs once (i.e., gets just one message). The thread starts but then you exit the loop and do join() which would have the effect of synchronous behaviour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to use active_count() when joining dead threads because the only threads you're interested in are in your *threads* list.

Implement this function...

```
def remove_dead_threads(_list):
    for thread in [t for t in _list if not t.is_alive()]:
        thread.join()
        _list.remove(thread)
```

Then, as the first line of code after *try:* do...

```
remove_dead_threads(threads)
```

This will clean up your *threads* list by joining those that are no longer alive.

You could also consider using a ThreadPoolExecutor to make pool management easier